# How to design a dynamic table data structure with EF Core Fluent API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to store data in SQL tables. My structure looks like an Excel table (or any kind of table). There are Tables with Columns, Rows, and Cells in the intersections.
My domain models are:

```cs
public class Table {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Column {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TableId { get; set; }
    
    public Table Table { get; set; }
}

public class Row {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
    public int TableId { get; set; }
    
    public Table Table { get; set; }
}

public class Cell {
    public int RowId { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public int TableId { get; set; }
    
    public string CellValue { get; set; }
    
    public Column Column { get; set; }
    public Row Row { get; set; }
}
```

The tricky part is at the Cells, where I use a composite key with the `RowId`, `ColumnName` and `TableId`.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Table>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Columns)
        .WithOne(x => x.Table)
        .HasForeignKey(x => new { x.TableId, x.Name });
        
    builder.Entity<Column>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.TableId, x.Name });
        
    builder.Entity<Row>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Table)
        .WithMany(x => x.Rows);
    builder.Entity<Row>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Cells)
        .WithOne(x => x.Row)
        .HasForeignKey(x => new { x.RowId, x.ColumnName, x.TableId });
    
    builder.Entity<Cell>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.RowId, x.ColumnName, x.TableId });
}
```

Unfortunately I get an exception when trying to add a Table to the database.

> InvalidOperationException: The relationship from 'Cell.Row' to 'Row.Cells' with foreign key properties {'RowId' : int, 'ColumnName' : string, 'TableId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.

I published my sample repo to GitHub, maybe it helps to understand and test.
https://github.com/kodaniel/TableDbContextSample

This example works fine when I use a simple Id PK field instead of a composite key, but I think a Cell.Id property would be totally unnecessary, because the Table.Id, Column.Name and Row.Id can obviously identify a specific Cell. So I guess this approach should work, the only problem is that I don't know where do I mess the model building.

Comment: EF is an ORM - an Object to Relational Mapper. It's meant to Map Objects to Relational tables, not be an abstract data access API. That's what the underlying ADO.NET is for. What you try to do is recreate the low-level ADO.NET DataTable on top of the higher level EF. Table, Row and Cell aren't domain entities, unless you're building an ETL tool and you use those objects to store table configuratin

Comment: EF can already map any object to a table dynamically. You do need that object and that table though, and the mappings between them. That's the whole point. If you. want to map arbitrary objects to arbitrary SQL, a microORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#execute-a-query-and-map-it-to-a-list-of-dynamic-objects) is far better. You can map the results to specific types or retrieve them as `dynamic` object with  eg `var results=connection.Query(sql);`. If you want to access columns by name you can cast to  `IDictionary<string,object>`

Comment: I removed the relationship mappings from the OnModelCreating() and it works fine now. I didn't know EF Core can figure it out dynamically how to connect tables based on property names. Maybe a dumb question, but why then need the HasOne(), HasMany() methods? In case if the models use unusual prop names and EF needs help to find it?